# Excel Unique values finder vba macro leaves out 2 values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a vba macro to find unique values in a certain column like this:

```
Function FillInVerantwoordelijken(Sheet As String)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("B2:B65000").AdvancedFilter     Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("A4"), Unique:=True
End Function
```

As far as I know this should work with the data I have but at the moment (with every column I try that needs this calculation) it skips 2 values that are there for some reason. For example, where I should have an output of 5 values I get 3.

Any idea? Is this the wrong way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I did a remove row a couple of times and I forgot about that. When I removed those lines it was solved. So, this vba macro works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if I understand your problem well, but you can use a Pivot Table to find out the unique values.

1. Create a Pivot Table
2. Drag and Drop the column in the rows part of the Pivot Table
3. Drag and Dtop the column in the values part of the Pivot Table.
4. Order by the Count in a descending order

The Excel will count how many records there are for each key (your column B).

This way, the records that has a count > 1 aren't unique.

Sometimes I use this solution to discover if my dataset has a repeated key.

Comment: It's fine now. It was just a problem with removing rows from the worksheet. That's why I lost two values. Thanks for the input though :)